# What are the security risks involved with publishing a Shiny app on shinyapps.io that connects to a SQL Server database?

Tags: r, sql-server, shiny, odbc

I have been asked for a very specific report/dashboard for end users that would work best as a Shiny app. Once the app is finished, my plan is for us to get a paid subscription on shinyapps.io and publish the app there using username and password authentication for the end users.

One of the asks is to have the data be updated in real time. This is not something that is mandatory but it is preferable. In order to do that, I have been using the odbc and DBI packages in R to connect to our SQL Server database. I asked the administrator of our SQL Server database to whitelist specific shinyapps.io IP addresses in order to allow the published Shiny app to connect to the database (same thing outlined in this article: https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html#firewalls)

The administrator of the database (who is obviously not the same person who requested this report- actually, he is an external consultant) expressed concern about "having the database server being public-facing and having the data accessed and stored from outside of the companies (sic) network." This person is unfamiliar with Shiny or R in general but he obviously knows a lot more about database security than me. The database administrator did not necessarily say that he was opposed to the project but he did bring up his concerns. I'm going to talk with our own internal IT team sometime this week about the project to give them further clarity on what I plan to do and to get their feedback on it.

So my question is- what are the security risks involved with publishing a Shiny app on shinyapps.io that connects to our database, and is there best-practice steps I can take to mitigate them as much as possible?

One obvious issue I know that I will have to fix before publishing the app is that my app.R code includes my username and password for the database, as you can see below:

```
is_local = Sys.getenv('SHINY_PORT') == ""

server = "server"
database = "database"
uid = "username"
pwd = "password"

dbConnector <- function(server, database, uid, pwd, 
                        local=TRUE, port=1433, tds_version=7.0){
  if(local){
    DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                   Driver = "SQL Server",
                   Server = server, 
                   Database = database, 
                   Uid = uid, 
                   Pwd = pwd,
                   Trusted_Connection = "True"
    )
    
  }else{
    DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                   Driver   = "FreeTDS",
                   Database = database,
                   Uid      = uid,
                   Pwd      = pwd,
                   Server   = server,
                   Port     = port,
                   TDS_Version=tds_version
    )
  }
}
```

Does anybody know a workaround to entering your database username and password into the app.R code when publishing the app? And are there any other security risks I should be aware of? I appreciate any help that can be provided in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you my perspective on data security as a DBA & my top concerns in your case:

1. Using a SaaS product hosted in the cloud by a 3rd party such as shinyapps.io means that the data will be pulled outside your company's network. This may result in your company losing control of its data, e.g. due to increased risks of data breach.
   I don't know what the data is but I suspect it is most likely to be corporate, private or sensitive data given your admin's response. If it's anything other than public or sample data, then a breach is likely to be a major problem for your company.
   Also, your company is likely to have requirements with regards to data protection when entering into contracts with 3rd parties to host its data. Depending on what the data is, the requirements may originate externally, e.g. GDPR for personal data. That you haven't mentioned data protection makes me think that you are not fully aware of or sufficiently attentive to these requirements in your desire to get your project delivered.
2. That your admin has expressed concern about "having the database server being public-facing" makes me think that the server is currently only accessible from within your network & exposing it to the public internet is a major change that can result in serious security issues as the server will no longer have the same level of protection that your firewall currently offers.
   The implications of this step need to be fully understood by the business stakeholders (e.g. management, data owners), including what might happen to their data in a worst case scenario & how that might affect their business.
   Likewise, the implementation of the change needs to be fully planned & stress-tested by the technical staff to minimise the potential for breach. This is not as simple as opening up a few firewall rules.
3. The technical lead for the R Shiny side of the solution needs to have a good understanding of the security implications of their actions & what practices to follow to minimise risk. As far as I can gather from your post, the technical lead for R Shiny is ***you*** & to be honest, if you're having to resort to asking random people from the internet how to securely implement your solution, then you don't have the expertise to deliver this project securely using this tool. I don't say this to be cruel, but you need to be aware that your technical limitations in this area present a big risk.

As you've probably noticed, none of my points are particularly technical. They are all related to how you approach solving the problem in a secure manner - planning appropriately, assessing risk, determining whether your organisation has the skillset required to securely implement & maintain the proposed solution. Before you try to implement a technical solution, take a step back & think about what problem that solution is supposed to solve & what other, potentially bigger problems you may be introducing just to get there. It's as important for you to cover yourself as a professional in this regard as it is for your company to do so - you really don't want to be the developer that caused a major external data breach of sensitive company data!

Comment: Deirdre, I greatly appreciate your honest feedback. After writing the OP, I have decided to not connect to our database when publishing the app. Instead, I will publish the app with a dataset that I will have to manually update each month on the backend, but the actual database will not be connected to inside of the Shiny app.

Comment: This addresses some of the risks however, if you haven't already done so, I also strongly recommend that you run this past your Data Protection Officer or equivalent to ensure that the business is happy with their data being stored outside the company network.